# Php | validate base64_decode as image | Not working

Tags: php, jquery

I created a function that will return the filetype of the supplied base64_decode argument. If it's not an image, the function will return false. However, when passing in encoded images (via jquery ajax (FormData object)) the function returns false everytime. I have tried many things, but am unable to get it working.

EDIT: I am now getting a Javascript error, here it is : 
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0"

```
function base64_extension($base64){
    $base64 = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,", "", $base64);
    $base64 = base64_decode($base64);

    $base64 = imagecreatefromstring($base64);

    if(!$base64){
        return 0; /* Not image */
    }


    if(imagepng($base64)){
        imagedestroy($base64);
        return 1;
    }else if(imagejpeg($base64)){
        imagedestroy($base64);
        return 2;
    }
    else if(imagegif($base64)){
        imagedestroy($base64);
        return 3;
    }
    else{
        return 4; /* Not image */
    }
}
```

## CLIENT

```
var cropCanvas = $('#user-img').cropper('getCroppedCanvas');
var cropImg = cropCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('pic', cropImg);
```

Then I pass the formData into ajax here.

Comment: Once you have an image created with any of the `imagecreate*` functions, you can output any type of image like `png`, `jpg`, `gif` regardless of what the input format was. Creating the image means it is in `GD`'s format that the extension can manipulate and then output in any image format it understands.

Comment: Also, do you have an example of the image data you are decoding? If I remember correctly, data sent over from ajax like that includes a content type. If you are not stripping that out, you will get bad `base64_decode`'d data. Meaning that you can't create an image from it.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I updated the question with the relevant client code.

Comment: Well, `toDataURL` includes the content type, like `data:image/png;base64,`. You need to remove that before trying to `base64_decode` because that is required for a data url, but isn't part of the `base64_encode`'d data. So `base64_decode` will return some other invalid binary data for the image.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn What if I am ajaxing .png, .gif, and .jpg? As in, depending on which type of file the user uploads. What would I pass in the toDataURL? Also, you're saying that I should remove the text that I pass into that method from my $base64 variable?

Comment: data urls all follow the same basic format. Here is the documentation on how they are formatted: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs. For images, the data type is typically `image/png` where `png` is the type of image and can be `jpeg` or `gif` respectively. Since image data is binary, it almost always includes the `base64`. If you want to test for images, you could just explode on comma like `explode(',', $data, 2)` and key `1` will be the base64 encoded data. Decode that and run your tests.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Okay. So I should pass in the format ("image/png") into the dataURL function in Javascript? Sorry for all the questions, it's a bit confusing to me. Then, in PHP, I should remove the string "data:image/png;base64," from my base64 BEFORE decoding?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I added this code $base64 = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,");. This removed all the errors, but the function is returning false for some reason.. I will update code

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Turns out I had the str_replace wrong, forgot the who next parameters. But now that I did that, I get a javascript error. Posted above.

Comment: I am going to create a new question. The chat is getting awfully long :)

Answer (score -1):

As Jonathan Kuhn said

> Once you have an image created with any of the imagecreate* functions, you can output any type of image like png, jpg, gif regardless of what the input format was. Creating the image means it is in GD's format that the extension can manipulate and then output in any image format it understands.

So your way is wrong you can get the MIME Type of Decoded base64 with finfo_* functions.

For Example :

```
$base64 = base64_decode($base64);
$finfo_handler = finfo_open();
$allowed_types = ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/gif"];
$mime_type = finfo_buffer($finfo_handler, $base64, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
finfo_close($finfo_handler);
if(!in_array($mime_type, $allowed_types)){
    // Mime Type is not JPEG or PNG or GIF
    return false;
}else{
    // Mime Type is in Array and returns first index of exploded string by "/" char.
    // That means for image/jpeg exploded_array = [ 0 => "image", 1 => "jpeg"]
    // and it returns first index "jpeg" for "image/png" it returns "png"
    return explode("/", $mime_type)[1];
}
```

Comment: Does this account for if people put .png extensions on non-image files?

Comment: This doesn't count because of "file name extensions" and "file format" are different things. Base64 encoding doesn't give you encoded file name, it gives you Base 64 Encoded string of Formatted File's data.

Comment: But is it secure?

Comment: Yes it is. As i said finfo checks Format Header of String so browser does.

Comment: I am getting an internal error 500 when executing your code from ajax :\

Comment: Calling the imagepng method causes this problem. It causes a JSON.parse error in my Javascript code..